# Scala reflection: get all constructor arguments of a specific type

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I want to create a general purpose method `def getOptionalArgs[T](): List[String]` such that when passed a type, it returns the list of all arguments to that type that are an `Option[_]`

E.g. I have a `case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Option[String])`. In this case, `getOptionalArgs[Foo]()` would return `List("baz")`.

I've been messing around with the reflections library, and I think I'm close via:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe, universe => ru}

def getOptionalArgs[T]() = {
 val constructor = ru.typeOf[T].decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
 ...
}
```

But I cant figure out how map/filter the reflected constructors parameters. What is missing here?

**Update**

`constructor.paramLists.head.map(t => (t.name.toString, t.info))` will return `List[(String, reflect.runtime.universe.Type)] = List((bar,Int), (baz,Option[Int]))`. So Its very close. Now I have to be able to figure out how to test equality between `Type`, and no, `equals` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: May I ask, why do you need this? Are you sure runtime reflection is the best answer to your meta-problem?

Comment: Its... complicated. I'm writing a spark application using the Dataset API and lots of case classes. I need to be able to construct arbitrary filters on the data depending on the type signature of said classes.  There are other ways of achieving the same results, but not without a lot of overhead.

Comment: Oh well, **Spark** is already an inefficient and unsafe pile of runtime reflection nevertheless. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
val constructor = ru.typeOf[I].decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
val notOptionalColNames = constructor.paramLists.head
      .map(t => (t.name.toString, t.info))
      .filter(t => !(t._2 <:< typeTag[Option[_]].tpe)).map(_._1)
```